# Wrong text instead of reference numbers with the spbasic bibiography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am writing a paper to a Springer journal and I am trying to use [their](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour2/bibtex/spbasic.bst)  `\bibliographystyle{spbasic}` However, instead of the number of the reference in the list of references I get something as:

> [Hundsdorfer et al(1995)Hundsdorfer, Koren, van Loon, and Verwer]

followed by the citation

What should I do to get the number in the square brackets?

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\begin{document}
\cite{Hundsdorfer:adv}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic} 
\bibliography{moje.bib}   % name your BibTeX data base

\end{document}
```

I may have to do the bibliography manually, as no Springer provided bibtex style produces the output that can be seen in the journal articles.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Wouldn't `\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}` do what you want? Numeric references, that is. If they provide a style, it means that they are satisfied with the output it produces.

Comment: It's strange. The actual articles in the journal have certainly a different style, then this one, but other article in review I have seen used apparently also `\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}`, so I will do the same.

Comment: The format of the citation suggests the bibliography style is for `natbib`. Try to add `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Guido Thank you, now it looks like in the journal, at least at the first look. If you write an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @VladimirF On your comment about fixing manually the bibliography: based on my experience with Springer, their editorial staff is going to edit the references anyway for the final production.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The format of the citation, i.e., `[Short author(year)Long author]` suggests that the bibliography file (`.bbl`) produced by the bibliography stye `spbasic` is for `natbib`. Thus adding

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

should address the issue.