# Springer bibliography issue - spbasic

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using  Springer's template svjour3.cls. Since it can be easy to obtain package, for example [here](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/LaTeX.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-468198-0) I am getting directly to the problem. I have the following MWE, some part comes from directly template

```
\documentclass[smallextended,natbib]{svjour3} 
%\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
 Unlike \cite{harsanyi73}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{bibch1}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that according to manual I need to write natbib in `\documentclass[smallextended,natbib]{svjour3}`, however, I am getting the error `Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.` Also error is `\providecommand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers`. I added natbib as usual i.e. `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` and I got the same error. However, it works fine if I change round to numbers. I have already checked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75182/issue-with-springer-spbasic) or [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74634/problem-with-springer-bibliography-style), but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. Thanks for any help in advance!

Edit: Here is an example of bibliography

```
  @article{harsanyi73,
   author = {Harsanyi, John C.},
   title = {Games with Randomly Disturbed Payoffs: A New Rationale for Mixed-Strategy     Equilibrium Points},
    year = {1973},
 journal = {International Journal of Game Theory},
  volume = {2},
  pages = {1--23},
  }
```

Comment: in additiom to the unrelated eps file the document ends `\en{document}` presumably you didn't test it before posting. Also `C:/Local Tex Files/bibtex/bib/misc/bibch1` is not going to work for most people, just use  `\bibliography{bibch1}` and supply a test bib file that shows the problem.

Comment: I have edited in the light of above comments. Still, as I expected the problem is there.

Comment: Thanks for posting usable code. Have you tried blowing away all aux files and recompiling from scratch? The reason I ask is that `spbasic` is a bibliography style that will indeed produce authoryear-style citation callouts if `natbib` is loaded without any options. Hence, the error message seems to be something of a misdirection, possibly because of some corrupted code in one of the aux files.

Comment: @Mico, I have tried a couple of times erasing all files and by recompiling, but couldn't figure it out what exactly problems is.

Comment: A problem might be `\cite{harsanyi 73}` with a space.

Answer (score 5):

It should have been stated in the User Guide, but `spbasic.bst` contains the following:

> For Springer medical, life sciences, chemistry, geology, engineering and       computer science publications.                                            For use with the natbib package (see below). Default is author-year citations. When citations are numbered, please use \usepackage[**numbers**]{natbib}. A lack of punctuation is the key feature.

Comment: Thank you! Adding `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` fixed my problem of the references formatting. This answer should have been accepted.